# How to change modal data dynamically using ag-grid in same model on two different onclick events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

- I am trying to call the same modal on  **two different icon clicks**. I need to toggle only single columnDef to toggle in a grid on two different function calls.
  Icons as buttons to fade-in the modal.
- Also, I need to toggle the modal title like "**Process**"(keeping unchanged) To "**Process** *A*" and "**Process** *B*"

**My Sample HTML** as follows

```
<!-- first icon with myFuncA() -->
<label data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo" data-ng-click="myFuncA()" title="Modal {{X}}">
                <span class="fa fa-dollar iconColor fa-custom-size"></span>
            </label>

<!-- first icon with myFuncB() -->
<label data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo" data-ng-click="myFuncB()" title="Modal {{Y}}">
                <span class="fa fa-credit-card iconColor fa-custom-size"></span>
            </label>     

<!-- my modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="demo" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header customPopup">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <!-- title i need to toggel as per discription in question -->
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal {{ }} </h4> 
            </div>
            <!-- grid I wish to keep same on both function calls -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding:10px;">
                <div id="agGrid" ng-style="{'width' : '100%', 'height' : '350px'}" ag-grid="agGridOptions" class="ag-blue ag-fresh ag-basic"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btnBackground customBtn-75" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" data-ng-disabled="saveButtonDisable" class="btn btnColor customBtn-75" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="update('true')">Proceed</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Script for **gridOptions** and **ColDefs**

```
$scope.agListGridOptions = {
            columnDefs: $scope.agColumnDefs,
            enableFilter: true,
            rowDeselection: true,
            enableColResize: true,
            rowHeight: 30,
            headerHeight: 35,
            suppressRowClickSelection: true,
            suppressScrollLag: true,
            angularCompileRows: true,
            icons: {
                groupExpanded: '<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',
                groupContracted: '<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',
                menu: '<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',
                columnGroupOpened: '<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',
                columnGroupClosed: '<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',
                filter: '<i class="fa fa-filter fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',
                sortAscending: '<i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',
                sortDescending: '<i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-lg customPointer iconColor"/>',

            },
            overlayNoRowsTemplate: '<span class="ag-overlay-no-rows-center">No Records to show</span>',
        };

       $scope.agColumnDefs = [{
            headerName: "SR",
            field: "UserID",
            width: 85,
            hide: true
        }, {
            headerName: "Column A",
            field: "EmpName",
            width: 170,
            cellClass: "text-align-left"
        }, {
            headerName: "Column B",
            field: "CurrentLWP",
            width: 120,

        }, {
            headerName: "Deduct A",
            field: "deductA",
            width: 85,
            editable: false,
            cellRenderer: cellRendererForDeductA,
            cellClass: "text-align-right"
        }, {
            headerName: "Deduct B",
            field: "deductB",
            width: 85,
            editable: false,
            cellRenderer: cellRendererForDeductB,
            cellClass: "text-align-right"
        }];
```

Hi flocks,

I need to toggle the columns with **headName** : "Deduct A" and "Deduct B" in same grid

Used *cellRendererForDeductA* and *cellRendererForDeductB* for some validations for perticular column cells.

Comment: Downvoters please answer the question then respond.

Comment: does the below answer solve your problem? If so could you accept it so others users having the same question can be benefited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call these functions by passing true or false on click of the button or your icon click? Haven't tested this code, but should work.

```
<button (click)="showDeductA(true)">Show DeductA</button>

showDeductA(show) {
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnVisible("deductA", show);
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnVisible("deductB", !show);
  }

showDeductB(show) {
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnVisible("deductB", show);
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnVisible("deductA", !show);
  }
```